# Error with audioEngine.start() in interfacecontroller on Watchos3

Tags: avfoundation, swift3, xcode8, avaudioengine, watchos-3

in the init method i use

audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

to init my audioEngine and then after button "record" is click i start my engine..

```
    audioEngine.prepare()
    do{
        try audioEngine.start()
    }catch {
        print("audioEngine start failed")
    }
```

but i comes to an error 
error : 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Have you attached `AVAudioPlayerNode`'s to it?
This is how I'm starting my audioEngine in a watchos3 app

http://pastebin.com/Xf7Bi3ru

EDIT: Added pastebin link for formatting.